# Need array key to match another array key

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

With my table setup (which isn't the proper setup, I know), what is the best way to group `subcontent` data in one email to send to the user if the `branches.id` is in the `users.notify` field?

My current code is below but I can't get the branch names to match (`if($user_value->branch===$key)`), and I just feel like there is a better way to accomplish what I need to do.

MySQL (tables are not setup the best, but it is what it is, for now)

```
# `subcontent` table (left out `date` field)
+-----+--------------+----------+
| id  | title        | branch   |
+-----+--------------+----------+
| 147 | Subcontent 1 | -50-100- |
| 588 | Subcontent 2 | -50-     |
| 696 | Subcontent 3 | -50-70-  |
+-----+--------------+----------+

# `branches` table
+-----+----------+
|  id | branch   |
+-----+----------+
|  50 | Branch 1 |
|  70 | Branch 2 |
| 100 | Branch 3 |
+-----+----------+

# `users` table
+----+--------+----------+
| id | name   | notify   |
+----+--------+----------+
|  1 | User 1 | -50-     |
|  2 | User 2 | -70-100- |
|  3 | User 3 | -100-    |
+----+--------+----------+
```

PHP

```
# Get current date.
$datetime_obj=new DateTime();
# Format the current date.
$today=$datetime_obj->format('Y-m-d');

# Subtract 7 days from the current date.
$datetime_obj->sub(new DateInterval('P7D'));
# Format the past date.
$one_week_ago=$datetime_obj->format('Y-m-d');

$sql="SELECT `sc`.`id`,
             `sc`.`title`,
             `sc`.`date`,
             `b`.`branch`
    FROM `subcontent` AS sc
    INNER JOIN `branches` AS b ON SUBSTRING_INDEX(TRIM(BOTH '-' FROM `sc`.`branch`), '-', 1)=`b`.`id`
    WHERE `sc`.`date` >= $one_week_ago
    ORDER BY `sc`.`date` DESC";
$all_subcontent=$db->get_results($sql);

# If there was content posted in the last week...
if(!empty($all_subcontent))
{
    $branch_content=array();
    # Loop through the subcontent.
    foreach($all_subcontent as $subcontent)
    {
        # Build a new array.
        $branch_content[$subcontent->branch][]=array(
            'id'=>$subcontent->id,
            'title'=>$subcontent->title,
            'date'=>$subcontent->date,
            'domain'=>$subcontent->domain
        );
    }
    # Results below.
    //print_r($branch_content);

    $users_sql="SELECT `u`.`email`,
                       `u`.`notify`,
                       `b`.`branch`
                FROM `users` AS u
                INNER JOIN `branches` AS b ON SUBSTRING_INDEX(TRIM(BOTH '-' FROM `u`.`notify`), '-', 1)=`b`.`id`
                WHERE `u`.`notify` IS NOT NULL";
    $users=$db->get_results($users_sql);
    # Results below.
    //print_r($users);

    $branch_users=array();

    $subject=DOMAIN_NAME.' News: '.$one_week_ago.' to '.$today;
    # Loop through the users.
    foreach($users as $user_key=>$user_value)
    {
        # Loop through the new array.
        foreach($branch_content as $key=>$value)
        {
            # Branch names never match up!
            # Does the users branch match the branch we're currently looping through?
            if($user_value->branch===$key)
            {
                # Build a new array.
                $branch_users[$user_key]['email']=$user_value->email;
                $branch_users[$user_key]['body']='The following news was posted on '.$key.' at '.DOMAIN_NAME.'<br />'.
                    'Click the title to read more.<br />'.
                    '<ul>';
                foreach($value as $row)
                {
                    $branch_users[$user_key]['body'].='<li>'.
                        $row['date'].'<br />'.
                        '<a href="http://'.DOMAIN_NAME.'/'.$key.'/?post='.$row['id'].'">'.$row['title'].'</a><br />'.
                        '</li>';
                }
                $branch_users[$user_key]['body'].='</ul><br />';
            }
        }
    }
    # Results below.
    //print_r($branch_users);

    # Loop through $branch_users and send emails
}
```

$branch_content results

```
Array
(
    [branch_1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 147
                    [title] => Subcontent 1
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 588
                    [title] => Subcontent 2
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 696
                    [title] => Subcontent 3
                )
        )

    [branch_2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 696
                    [title] => Subcontent 3
                )
        )

    [branch_3] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 147
                    [title] => Subcontent 1
                )
        )
)
```

$users results (branch only lists one branch even though notify has multiple branches, which is fine)

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [email] => user_1@example.com
            [notify] => -50-
            [branch] => branch_1
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [email] => user_2@example.com
            [notify] => -70-100-
            [branch] => branch_2
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [email] => user_3@example.com
            [notify] => -100-
            [branch] => branch_3
        )
)
```

$branch_users result

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [email] => user_1@example.com
            [body] => The following news was posted on Branch 1 at example.com<br />Click the title to read more.<br /><ul><li><date><br /><a href="http://example.com/branch_1/?post=147">Subcontent 1</a><br /></li></ul><br />The following news was posted on Branch 1 at example.com<br />Click the title to read more.<br /><ul><li><date><br /><a href="http://example.com/branch_1/?post=588">Subcontent 2</a><br /></li></ul><br />The following news was posted on Branch 1 at example.com<br />Click the title to read more.<br /><ul><li><date><br /><a href="http://example.com/branch_1/?post=696">Subcontent 3</a><br /></li></ul><br />
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [email] => user_2@example.com
            [body] => The following news was posted on Branch 2 at example.com<br />Click the title to read more.<br /><ul><li><date><br /><a href="http://example.com/branch_2/?post=696">Subcontent 3</a><br /></li></ul><br />The following news was posted on Branch 3 at example.com<br />Click the title to read more.<br /><ul><li><date><br /><a href="http://example.com/branch_3/?post=588">Subcontent 2</a><br /></li></ul><br />
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [email] => user_3@example.com
            [body] => The following news was posted on Branch 3 at example.com<br />Click the title to read more.<br /><ul><li><date><br /><a href="http://example.com/branch_3/?post=147">Subcontent 1</a><br /></li></ul><br />
        )
)
```

Comment: I don't understand what your problem is. You already know that your tables aren't setup properly. So what do you expect actually?

Comment: I'm trying to focus to understand your needs, but it's not that easy...maybe it would be easier if you say what you're trying to accomplish. Even just the desired output you're looking for

Comment: Your $user_value->branch has names like (Branch 1, Branch 3). Your keys are (branch_1,branch_3). So they will not match.

Comment: @phaberest I've added the desired results to the bottom. I know it's confusing, but fixing the tables is not an option :(

Comment: @MartavisGriffin That was just a mistake in my post

Comment: just explode the notify value and match with the branch ids you can fetch separately